# FileMaker Pro 10 and xDBC ODBC Plugin

Tags: odbc, filemaker

Has anyone got a ODBC data source setup for FileMaker Pro 10 on Windows?

The documentation that ships with FileMaker Pro 10 does not make sense as it is saying to click on a set-up file that does not exist.

None of the forums are providing an answer either.

Comment: For the record this has changed again in FM 11, and the SequelLink is no longer used or supported.

Answer (score 1):

On your FileMaker Server 10 installation disk there should be a folder called 'xDBC' with a sub-folder 'ODBC Client Driver Installer'.

Inside is a launcher called 'setup.exe'. (There should also be 'DataDirect SequeLink 5.5 Client for ODBC.msi' in the same location, which you could try running directly.)

Once the driver is installed, you can set up an ODBC DSN with the ODBC Data Source Administrator accessed from Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  I discovered this page for Filemaker 7.0 (http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/filemaker_mysql_whitepaper/filemaker_to_mysql_whitepaper01.htm).  Try going up to the File/sharing/ODBC menu.  I think it might work.

Or maybe not.  It appears that FM is selling an SQL Product.  This might work: http://www.filemakertrial.com/sqlkit/

Mike